# Clip a GeoTIFF based on a bounding box coordinates using rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, masking, python-window

I would like to clip a geodaframe based on coordinates. Let's say that I have the following bounding box from a GeoPandas dataframe. The projection is `mollweide`.

```
gdf.boundary.plot()
```

[image]

```
gdf.total_bounds
array([-7377166.52915863, -4078511.43342756, -3468631.03817339,
         651590.86424916])
```

I want to `mask` a geotiff that contains information at global scale on that region.

This is what I am doing:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.plot import show
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
## read file
src = rasterio.open(filepath)
## mask
x0, y0, x1, y1 = gdf.total_bounds
rst = src.read(1, window=from_bounds(x0, y0, x1, y1, src.transform))
## show
f,ax=plt.subplots()
image_hidden = ax.imshow(rst, cmap='cubehelix_r', vmin=0, vmax=5)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# plot on the same axis with rio.plot.show
image = show(rst,transform=src.transform,  ax=ax, cmap='cubehelix_r',vmin=0, vmax=5)
# add colorbar using the now hidden image
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(image_hidden, cax=cax)
gdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax,color='red',lw=1)
```

[image]

It seems that I am not giving the right transform information. How can I specify the rigth transform information when I read the file?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `mask` function of *rasterio* you can do the following. Let's imagine that `full_dataset` is your rasterio raster object and `shapefile` is your polygon to clip the raster (ESRI Shapefile format).

Firs import the shapefile using geopandas:

```
import rasterio as rio
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import mapping

shapefile = gpd.read_file('../data/rcr/shapefile_to_clip.shp')
```

Then check the CRS of `full_dataset` and `shapefile`. If these are different, reproject the shapefile:

```
full_dataset.crs
shapefile.crs

shapefile = shapefile.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'}) # EPSG 4326: WGS84
```

Finally, crop the raster using `mask`:

```
geoms = shapefile.geometry.values
geometry = geoms[0] # Get the first and only geometry in the ESRI Shapefile. Your box boundaries.
feature = [mapping(geometry)] # Required conversion

clipped_dataset, out_transform = mask(full_dataset, feature, crop=True)
```

Finally check the shape of your new raster:

```
clipped_dataset.shape
```